# Failing to run Spark actions on Oozie in HDP 2.5.0 (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid ContainerId)

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, oozie

I am trying to run a simple spark Java application. I can run the application by spark submit in our cluster

my job.properties file is as follow:

```
nameNode=hdfs://auper01-01-20-01-0.prod.vroc.com.au:8020
jobTracker=auper01-02-10-01-0.prod.vroc.com.au:8050
master=yarn-cluster
queueName=default
#examplesRoot=examples
oozie.use.system.libpath=true
oozie.wf.application.path=${nameNode}/user/livy
oozie.libpath=${nameNode}/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_20161001110339/spark
```

in the oozie.libpath, I have two files one is oozie-sharelib-spark-4.2.0.2.5.0.0-1245.jar and another is my spark application jar

the workflow.xml file is in my (user/livy) directory and I have also uplodede my application jar to that directory as well to avoif getting not classfound experion for spark submit, the file is as follow:

```
<workflow-app xmlns='uri:oozie:workflow:0.5' name='SparkExample'>
    <start to='spark-node' />

    <action name='spark-node'>
        <spark xmlns="uri:oozie:spark-action:0.1">
            <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
            <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
            <master>${master}</master>
            <name>Spark-Oozie</name>
            <class>au.com.vroc.mdm.SimpleApp</class>
            <jar>${nameNode}/tmp/simple-project/mdm-mahdi.jar</jar>
        </spark>
        <ok to="end" />
        <error to="fail" />
    </action>

    <kill name="fail">
        <message>Workflow failed, error
            message[${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}]
        </message>
    </kill>
    <end name='end' />
</workflow-app>
```

I can sucesfully initite oozie and get an application id, when I go to oozie logs my spark log has bellow exception

```
2017-05-26 16:51:01,880 ERROR [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster: Error starting MRAppMaster
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid ContainerId: container_e20_1489119643653_0943_02_000001
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.ConverterUtils.toContainerId(ConverterUtils.java:182)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster.main(MRAppMaster.java:1343)
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "e20"
        at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
        at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:589)
        at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:631)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.ConverterUtils.toApplicationAttemptId(ConverterUtils.java:137)
        at 

org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.ConverterUtils.toContainerId(ConverterUtils.java:177)

    ... 1 more
```

not sure why I get above error, any help would be apprecited.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your application jar does not contain any dependencies (which may cause this issue). This issue was reported at [HDP](https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/39184/242-spark-submit-got-invalid-containerid.html) and [IBM](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSWTQQ_2.0.0/solnguide/c_trd_trbls_javalangnumberformatexception.html).